# Embedly cards with Polymer not working on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, polymer, polymer-starter-kit, embedly

Starting with a clean version of the Polymer Starter Kit (2.0.1), I was attempting to implement some Embedly cards as described [in this post.](https://blog.embed.ly/embedly-cards-and-web-components-eaedfcef92ba#.3c3wmtnsm)

Everything is working fine on Firefox and Edge, but cards are not loading on Chrome.

I vaguely suspect this may be because the asynchronous XMLHttpRequest calls in the imported embedly platform javascript file were seen as synchronous, and deprecated on Chrome.

Anybody faced a similar issue?
Could you advice on a workaround?